# ошибка в коде | c#

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку должна сохраняться информация из текстбокса либо открываться новый файл в зависимости от названия самой кнопки, однако этого не происходит. В чём же ошибка?

```
private void ClickTestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ?? (sender as Control)?.Text) == nameof(button_load) ||
        ((sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ?? (sender as Control)?.Text) == nameof(loadToolStripMenuItem))
    {
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Текст|*.txt|Код C#|*.cs";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            fs.Close();
            textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
    else if (((sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ?? (sender as Control)?.Text) == nameof(button_save) ||
        ((sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ?? (sender as Control)?.Text) == nameof(saveToolStripMenuItem))
    {
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Текст|*.txt|Код C#|*.cs";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fname = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Cохранено!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Внутри if-ов код исполняется или условие всегда неверное?.

Comment: Исполняется, вроде

Comment: вы уверены, что ваш `else if (((sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ??...` относится к правильному `if`?

Comment: он не относится

Comment: выложи проект..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-Rb4_EzYOMbF9henNhZjB2b2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @codename0082016 вы посмотрели?

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva: А на какую кнопку вы нажимаете, и куда заходит выполнение? Попробуйте выражение `(sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ?? (sender as Control)?.Text` записать в отдельную локальную переменную и посмотреть в отладчике, что там приходит.

Comment: У вас имена не совпадают и условие не выполнится никогда `nameof(button_load) = "button_load" (sender as ButtonBase)?.Text = "Load" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nameof Используется для получения простого (неполного) строкового имени переменной, типа или члена.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn986596.aspx

Вы получаете имя переменной и сравниваете с надписью на кнопке

```
button_load.Text = "Load";
```

У вас `nameof(button_load) = "button_load"`

Если заменить `nameof(button_load)` на `"Load"` то работает

```
if (((sender as ButtonBase)?.Text ?? (sender as ToolStripMenuItem)?.Text) == "Load" )
```

Остальное делается аналогично

Comment: Но если нажимать из меню,то не работает

Comment: Обновлено. Control переправлено на ToolStripMenuItem